# NSUserDefault critical coding in ios9 swift?

Tags: swift, ios9, nsuserdefaults

I am following a tutorial in which I am saving data in a NSUserDefault type having the following code. It has comments but I can't get what's happening over here-

```
var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary() // if todoItems hasn't been set in user defaults, initialize todoDictionary to an empty dictionary using nil-coalescing operator (??)

        todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline": item.deadline, "title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY)
```

So what's actually happening here can anyone please explain a bit.
What is the `ITEMS_KEY` doing here ?

Comment: @lukesIvi This post isn't even about CoreData, but NSUserDefaults. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 is retrieving a dictionary from the UserDefaults with key `ITEMS_KEY`, when that fails, it instantiates an empty `Dictionary()`. That is what the null-coalescing operator means. ITEMS_KEY is a property you might have set somewhere (a constant).

Line 2 is setting a key-value to the dictionary.

Line 3 is writing the dictionary back to the NSUserDefaults.

Line 4 is double? Not sure if that is right.

Comment: UUID is a unique identifier for each item. So why it is writing todoDictionary[item.UUID]= . Can't we write as todoDictionary[]= . What difference does it make by writing the code that way & please check the comment written for that line. Can you give some more explanation for that part line.

Comment: When you execute that line of code, the following happens:

1) The dictionary gets a key which is the UUID of your device.
2) The value for that key is an array with items in it.

That way the app can reach into that dictionary and get the data you saved there (the array).

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but you are not getting it. As per the tutorial it was providing a unique UUID for each item in the particular dictionary. So that I can load my items from the disk storage whenever my app runs. Thats fine but what I am asking is if that is the case then what actually happens when you write an expression as tododictionary[items.UUID]? You can mark that todoDictionary gets value for each item like date,title,its UUID.

Comment: Fine then but it also writes in that particular comment that it provides UUID as a key for each item in the dictionary. So I think that todoDictionary is a dictionary having many item dictionary within it with their respective key i.e their UUID. So now I want to know about the syntax of adding values to the todoDictionary as todoDictionary[item.UUID]. So highlight this as per the comment. And check out my theory a bit. Rectify me if I am wrong. Thanks